# Find distinct length of string field using mongo shell

Tags: mongodb-query, mongo-shell

Given a mongo collection like:

```
col1   col2
1      "mango"
2      "banana"
3      "watermelon"
4      "orange"
```

How do I get the length of distinct string lengths of column col2? It would probably be using the strLenCP function but am not able to construct it just for the projection.

Expected output would be: 
(5, 6, 10)
since the distinct string lengths of (banana, orange) are 6, watermelon 10 and mango 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an aggregation pipeline by using `$strLenCP` within a `$group`:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Group documents by their col2 string length
    {$group: {_id: {$strLenCP: '$col2'}}}
])
```

Output:

```js
{ "_id" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 6 }
{ "_id" : 5 }
```